# How does compose update scroll state internally?

Tags: android, android-compose

As the Compose documents suggest, To make a composable stateless, We use [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) by replacing the state variable with two parameters: value and onValueChananged.

Something like this:

```
MyText(text: String, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit
```

However, in some cases, the composable function gets a value without state hoisting, for example when we are interested in reading `ScrollableState` or `LazyListState`, we pass a remembered state to the composable function:

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyRow(state = lazyListState) {...}
```

With the given code above, let's assume that `lazyListState` is indirectly used in `MyItem` composable:

```
items(items = myItems,
    key = { item -> item.id }) { item ->
    val someDerivedState by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
           someComputationsWithLazyListState(lazyListState)
        }
    }
    MyItem(item = item, deferredDerivedState = { someDerivedState })
}
```

Here is my question, How does compose keep `lazyListState` updated internally without passing it by something like oScrollstateChange?

Note that I'm not asking how to use LazyListState, The question is about how it works.

Comment: You passed it the state object, therefore it can set its properties (there is a callback somewhere internally).  The `onTextChanged` pattern where the developer needs to update the state themself turned out to have a lot of issues, and it's one the team is [moving away from](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text2/package-summary).

Comment: Hi @RyanM, Thanks for the response.  If I'm not mistaken, I see the state as an immutable value, I'm wondering how the state works in two ways and raises events as well. Honestly, I read some of the code but I couldn't figure it out. Is there any article or resource that you recommend to read?

Comment: I'd recommend just looking at the source code.  For example, [here is the current version of `LazyListState`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState.kt;l=92;drc=f707d8ed4e348da258d2c9525ac0c4477858b251).  Note that the property getters all just read from an internal object, which can be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It was easier than I thought, The short answer is `MutableState`!

Instead of `LazyListState`, I start with a simpler example. Let's assume there is an interface named `Person` with this contract:

```
interface Person {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
}
```

We want to update the age internally and let the Compose know, Here is how it is implemented:

```
internal class PersonImpl(override val name: String, age: Int) : Person {

    override var age: Int by mutableStateOf(age)
        private set

    override fun oneYearLater() {
        age += 1
    }
}
```

Also, we can provide an instance of `PersonImpl` as `Person` by a composable function, something like `rememberLazyListState` (But `LazyListState` is not an internal class):

```
@Composable
fun rememberPerson(name: String, age: Int): Person = remember {
    PersonImpl(name, age)
}
```

Note that `oneYearLater` is added to simulate internal updates of the class. Every time that we invoke this function, Compose knows the state is changed and If any composable accepts it as a state, There will be a recomposition:

```
val person = rememberPerson(name = "Farshad", age = 21)
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    val message by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            "${person.name} is ${person.age} years old!"
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = message,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium
    )
    Button(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), onClick = {
        person.oneYearLater()
    }) {
        Text(text = "Increase age by 1")
    }
}
```

So, every button click increases age by one and the Text will be updated.